# Max Number of Iterations/Clock Cycle

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

How to calculate maximum number of iterations executed in one Clock Cycle of a given frequency in System Verilog.

For example: Clock = 50MHz. How many iterations of a for loop can I execute in one cycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what kind of logic the `for` loop represents. As an example, consider a loop that counts the number bits set in a bus. That would get unrolled into a chain of adders. So you would need to look at the delay across each adder.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit.

As to a limit in hardware: in synthesis loops are unrolled and in hardware execute in parallel. The delay of the logic generated sets your maximum operating frequency, as with all HDL code.